# Extension method for List<T> Contains(T? object) how to?

Tags: c#

I want to write an extension method Like the Contains method of the List class  for the List class that takes an null able object. Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: `List<Nullable<T>>` already has it, isnt it? The point is, why do you want to do that check? `List<T>` can never have `T?` objects unless you cast to `T` before adding them. That makes the `Contains` check for `T?` futile. You should instead have a `List<T?>` collection which already has it anyway.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: why not `List<int?>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments on the other answer, it looks like you're trying to do something like

```
var myWantedIds = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
var matchingItems = myEntityFrameworkItems
    .Where(efItem => myWantedIds.Contains(efItem.NullableIdProperty));
```

Writing an overload of `Contains` won't help here, as it can't be translated into SQL.

One thing to try is to check if the list contains the non-null ID:

```
var myWantedIds = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
var matchingItems = myEntityFrameworkItems
    .Where(efItem => efItem.NullableIdProperty.HasValue &&
                     myWantedIds.Contains(efItem.NullableIdProperty.Value));
```

In case that also doesn't translate, you could also try to convert your search list to the nullable version:

```
var myWantedIds = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
var myNullableIds = myWantedIds.Select(i => new int?(i)).ToList();
var matchingItems = myEntityFrameworkItems
    .Where(efItem => myNullableIds.Contains(efItem.NullableIdProperty));
```